# Git Remote Push Error ! [remote rejected] master -> master (Could not update working tree to new HEAD)

Tags: git, github

I cloned a HackerRank repo on which they instruct to just use a regular clone i.e

`git clone https://10-142-1-122-4000.hackerrank.io/git-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx weather-tracker-xxxxxx`

Their instructions also say:

- Pushing code to the remote master branch will automatically update the code inside the editor.
- Only work with the master branch.
- Avoid force pushing to master.

The `pull`, `fetch` `commit` and `stage` happens normally without any issues but when I try to `push -u origin master`

Error:

`! [remote rejected] master -> master (Could not update working tree to new HEAD)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx-4000.hackerrank.io/git-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

Current logs show:

```
* 1f5fb0f - (HEAD -> master) edit routes (21 minutes ago) <mygithub>
* 92b4606 - add nodemon to dev enviroment (38 minutes ago) <mygithub>
* d566bbd - (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Set up project with stubs for JavaScript (89 minutes ago) <HackerRank>
* 9dca7c5 - (tag: initial) Initial Commit (3 hours ago) <HackerRank>
```

`git clone --bare` did not solve the issue.

Any thoughts on how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Make sure you have enough permission to push to maser. Maybe you can try to push to other branch: `git push origin HEAD:b1`

Comment: Are you sure it has not printed any remote output? Please provide full output of the push command

Comment: I have a similar issue. It let me do a test commit and then… all 408 errors. Won't let me push anything. Deleted my account and started over. Same exact result. Is there any sort of help aside from FAQ's on this service? Is it just an app with no support people?